# It's a good practice always restore controlfile before restore the database?

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

I'm beginner in Oracle, but I'd like know if it's a good practice always restore the control-file of a backup-set before restore the database. I ask this because always when I restore the control-file I need open the database with reset-logs option and I don't know if it's a good practice to do this.

If the answer is no, so when I need restore the control-file?

Comment: do you use an RMAN catalog for your backups?

Comment: Sometimes, lately I'm using just controlfile in my tests, in my work none database use catalog as well.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the nature of the failure and the need of recovery.  The ends-and-outs are too complex to put in a single answer here, but the [*Database Backup and Recovery User Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/toc.htm) has a whole section of scenarios on "[Diagnosing and Responding to Failures](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/part_dia.htm#BRADV325)". You would do well to study it.  And build yourself a private VM under VirtualBox, to practice on.

Recovering a database is the Prime Directive of any DBA.